# Getting "npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE npm ERR! errno 126" while running npm install

Tags: javascript, node.js, npm-install, node-cron, amazon-linux-2

I am trying to run npm install on my server and getting this error.

```
> node-cron@2.0.3 postinstall /home/workspace/AgreementCancellationProd/retrymechanism/node_modules/node-cron
> opencollective-postinstall

/usr/bin/env: node: Permission denied
npm WARN retrymechanism@1.0.0 No description
npm WARN retrymechanism@1.0.0 No repository field.

npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno 126
npm ERR! node-cron@2.0.3 postinstall: `opencollective-postinstall`
npm ERR! Exit status 126
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Failed at the node-cron@2.0.3 postinstall script.
npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     /root/.npm/_logs/2019-03-06T11_22_15_832Z-debug.log
```

NPM install is running fine on my local system but fails on server.

Also, when I try to install node-cron@2.0.3 using `npm install node-cron@2.0.3`, it throws the same error.

I am using `Amazon Linux` on EC2.

I've tried cleaning cache, deleting node_modules & package-lock.json and installing again. Nothing worked.

This is my package.json :

```
{
  "name": "retrymechanism",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "main": "index.js",
  "scripts": {
    "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1"
  },
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC",
  "dependencies": {
    "express": "^4.16.4",
    "fs": "0.0.1-security",
    "mysql2": "^1.6.5",
    "node-cron": "^2.0.3",
    "request": "^2.88.0",
    "sequelize": "^4.42.0"
  }
}
```

What could be the problem? Please help!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I ran into the same problem I used `yarn` to solve the issue I think it's related to the `npm` version :

```
yarn add node-cron@2.0.3
```

Comment: I used "yarn add node-cron@2.0.3" instead of "yarn install node-cron@2.0.3"

Comment: Great! Fixed :)

Answer (score 3):

That error means one of your js files needs to be marked as executable. Try:

```
chmod +x src/index.js
```

Answer (score 2):

For anyone having the same issue while deploying a **React JS** application with **Jenkins**, I improvised [@oabarca's answer above](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59818130/5630225) and it worked. Just make sure you have this line `chmod +x ./node_modules/.bin/react-scripts` after `npm install` and before `npm run build` like this:

```
pwd
npm install
chmod +x ./node_modules/.bin/react-scripts   # add this line
npm run build
# ..rest of the code here
```

Hope it saves someone some Googling time ;)

Answer (score 0):

Try to remove the "node-cron" from your package-json for a moment and then run npm install. 
If it works this way, there is a problem with node-cron and you might need to define a different version.