# npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE npm ERR! errno 126

Tags: node.js, reactjs, npm, yarnpkg

Firsty I should do `npm run build` then `npm run install`, but no matter what to type on the server I am getting this error.

```
sh: 1: react-app-rewired: Permission denied
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno 126
npm ERR! manager-polling-app-client@0.1.0 start: `react-app-rewired start`
npm ERR! Exit status 126
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Failed at the manager-polling-app-client@0.1.0 start script.
npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     /root/.npm/_logs/2020-01-08T05_17_59_301Z-debug.log
```

NPM install is running on my local system but fails on server.

I cleaned cache, deleted node_modules and package-lock.json and re-installed them, but it didn`t worked.

My `package.json`

```
{
  "name": "manager-polling-app-client",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@material-ui/core": "^3.9.3",
    "ajv": "^6.0.0",
    "ajv-keywords": "^3.2.0",
    "antd": "^3.16.3",
    "arui-feather": "^12.12.0",
    "b64-to-blob": "^1.2.19",
    "moment": "^2.22.2",
    "pdfmake": "^0.1.53",
    "prop-types": "^15.7.2",
    "react": "^16.11.0",
    "react-awesome-modal": "^2.0.5",
    "react-data-export": "^0.5.0",
    "react-dom": "^16.11.0",
    "react-export-excel": "^0.5.3",
    "react-router-dom": "^4.3.1",
    "react-scripts": "1.1.1",
    "react-select": "^2.4.2",
    "xlsx": "^0.14.4"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "start": "react-app-rewired start",
    "build": "react-app-rewired build",
    "test": "react-app-rewired test --env=jsdom",
    "eject": "react-scripts eject"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "babel-plugin-import": "^1.11.0",
    "react-app-rewire-less": "^2.1.3",
    "react-app-rewired": "^1.6.2"
  }
}
```

P.S. I found that I can change rights with chmod -R 777, but people say it`s a bad idea. Personally, it worked on the server and I do not wanna play with rights (worry that will crash it at , i think there is another way to solve issue.

P.P.S. If here I should use yarn, then I should `yarn add` on local system and then permanently use yarn on server?

P.P.P.S. I am really newbee in npm and in yarn... sorry if question seems stupid

Comment: Try to run it with `sudo`.

Comment: I tried , didn’t help

Comment: Watch this. It might help you. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55022219/getting-npm-err-code-elifecycle-npm-err-errno-126-while-running-npm-install

Comment: Yeah I saw it, I am newbee in npm and yarn. What should i do in my case?

Comment: try `yarn add manager-polling-app-client@0.1.0`